# Want to make a list only accessible by certain classes

Tags: c#, oop

So I have these classes (excluding main) public BankAccount, public static Bank
So I want to have a static list of all of the account that can only be read or
edited by the classes above

In main I should only be able to create accounts and
deposit or withdraw money from them?

How do I do it?

I don't have a prototype so you'll have to work with your imagination.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at Microsoft's documentation on access modifiers
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers

Comment: C#/.NET doesn't have C++'s notion of `friend` accessibility - the closest equivalent is `internal`. That said, what are you _really_ trying to accomplish - or is this just a learning-exercise?

Comment: It's just a learning exercise from my school. Obviously they aren't asking for something complex like this (for me).